# Parent to match one of child divs height

Tags: html, css

I have 2 columns, left and right. The left column is dynamic, the length of it depends on the content coming from backend. I also have background image which is an svg. I want the background image to have the length of the left child element.

[image how it should behave on different occasions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRVwu.png)

The html structure in a simplified way:

```
<div className="bg-row">
  <div className="col-1"></div>
  <div className="col-2"></div>
</div>
```

How to make the parent to match the height of the left child element?

Comment: you can do something like `document.querySelector('.bg-row').style.backgroundSize = document.querySelector('.col-1').getBoundingClientRect().height + 10px(some extra padding))`. You can remove that extra if you want.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?